# Palo Alto one to one NAT

Tags: nat

I am new to Palo Alto Firewalls.  I am working on a project using a PAN 3020 to setup some test networks.  We are moving from one date center to another and don't want to change IP addresses.

I am attaching a picture that describes what I would like to accomplish.[image]

Answer (score 1):

For one to One NAT you can refer below config
the same rule can work for bi direction traffic if you want
If you want to Dynamic NAT you can select translation type Dynamic IP

need to create one NAT rule
Policy ---> Nat rule
Name:any word
Original packet 
Source Zone --(zone belongs to the IP 10.199.20.1)
Source Ip address:10.199.20.1

Translated packet
Destination zone:
Destination interace: any
Destination

Source translation :
Ip address:10.194.128.1
Bidirectional : Yes